# Dealing with filename extensions - bash vs oascript

Tags: finder, applescript, bash

I have a script than closes open windows, but it only works when I have enabled the Finder "show all filename extensions" preference.  Is there a robust way to accomplish this regardless of the state of the filename extension preference?  I suppose I could try to close the file both with and without the extension, but that's an ugly solution

```
cd somedir
for file in * ; do
  echo file name is $file

osascript<<EOF
  tell application "Preview"
  close (every window whose name is "$file")
  end tell
EOF
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your shell variable `$file` will always have a file extension in tact, you need to use the `path` property for *Preview*'s `document`, which contains the full file path of the open file, including file extension:

```
cd somedir
for file in * ; do
  echo file name is $file

osascript<<EOF
  tell application "Preview"
    close (every document whose path ends with "$file")
  end tell
EOF
  sleep 1
done
```

This is slow, however, even without the `sleep` delay.  Another way you could do it is to enumerate the files in AppleScript instead:

```
osascript<<EOF
  use sys : application "System Events"
  use Preview : application "Preview"

  script
    property list : displayed name of every file ¬
                    in sys's folder "$somedir"
  end script

  repeat with f in result's list
    tell Preview's document named f to if exists ¬
    then close
  end repeat
EOF
```

This is almost instantaneous, and the `displayed name` property specifically uses the name as it's displayed in *Finder*, with or without its extension.  Therefore, it matches the `name` property of the *Preview* document.